# Dependency Injection for AzureFunction ServiceBus based on message information

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions, azureservicebus, multi-tenant

I am working on AzureFunction ServiceBus v3 which handle multi-tenant message. In message I will have TenantId and I will need to register DependencyInjection per message base on this TenantId.
What I tried so far:

1. At StartUp, I stored the IServiceCollection as static variable
2. Retrieve the TenantId from the serialized message in Function'd Run method
3. Update IServiceCollection based on above TenantId and retrieve the Service

   `_serviceCollection.AddTransient<ITenantIdResolver>(ctx => { return new CompanyResolver{TenantId=tenantId}; }); var service = _serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<T>();`

But it throw exception: `Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.IEnvironment' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Configuration.ScriptHostOptionsSetup'` I do some research and look like it was because I used IHttpClientFactory.
How can I fix this?

Or even better if there is a way to retrieve the message in StartUp, so I can inject the tenantId properly? Like
`serviceCollection.AddTransient<ITenantIdResolver>(ctx => {  var tenantId = GetServicebusMessage().TenantId;  return new CompanyResolver { TenantId=tenantId }; }`

Comment: this may not directly answer your question, but are you aware that you can use servicebus bindings https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8p8RmOg9iw ? this way you can have declarative access to your triggering message

Comment: Thank @AlexGordon, I knew how to read the triggering message, only problem with register service based on its value

Comment: You can solve this problem but using a factory pattern and then executing the code for a specific tenant based on tenantid. It doesn't really solve your question but it solves your problem and it might result in cleaner code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that would be the wrong order of things. Dependency injection should be setup before the message is being processed.

A resolver could be a solution. Register the resolver with the dependency injection container, and let the function be dependent on the resolver. Based on the message you get the right instance from the resolver. In this article it is explained better under "*IoC Container Registration #3 – Resolver + Factory Method Pattern*": https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/dependency-injection-on-azure-functions-5-ways-selecting/ba-p/1502394

Answer (score 1):

According to [Dependency injection for azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection), it's not possible to use the services at an early stage.

My suggestion is to change the architecture to "Durable Orchestrations" so you call an ActivityTrigger function from the orchestrator which gets back list of tenants then you fire other ActivityTriggers that will handle them.